In Angular 18 CSS is not applied on mat-form-field and other controls
I'm using Angular 18 and Angular Material dialog box.
When I open the angular material dialog box there CSS is not applied on Form-fields. They looks normal html components but when I click on text box then CSS is applied. All necessary modules are imported but still CSS is not appliend.
As shown in image
After I click on any text box on the form CSS is applied. as given in below image:
enter image description here
HTML Code is given below:
<h2 mat-dialog-title>Add Bank Branch</h2>
<form>
  <div class="content">
    <mat-dialog-content>
      <div class="row-cols-1">
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
          <mat-label>Branch Address</mat-label>
          <input name="BranchAddress" matInput formControlName="BranchAddress"/>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
      <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
        <mat-label>IFSC Code</mat-label>
        <input name="IFSCCode" matInput formControlName="IFSCCode" />
      </mat-form-field>

      <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>MICR Code</mat-label>
        <input name="MICRCode" matInput formControlName="MICRCode" />
      </mat-form-field>
    </mat-dialog-content>
  </div>
  <mat-dialog-actions>
    <button mat-button type="button">No Thanks</button>
    <button style="padding-left: 10px"
      color="primary"
      mat-raised-button
      mat-button
      type="submit"
      cdkFocusInitial >
      <mat-icon>add_circle</mat-icon>
      Save
    </button>
  </mat-dialog-actions>
</form>

TS code :>>>>>
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, Validators } from     
'@angular/forms';
import { MatButtonModule, MatIconButton } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatDialogActions, MatDialogClose, MatDialogContent, MatDialogTitle } from 
'@angular/material/dialog';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatIcon } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-branch',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    FormsModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatDialogTitle,
    MatDialogContent,
    MatDialogActions,
    MatDialogClose,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatIcon,
    MatIconButton
  ],
  templateUrl: './add-branch.component.html',
  styleUrl: './add-branch.component.css'
})
export class AddBranchComponent implements OnInit {

  branchForm!: FormGroup;
  constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) {}
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.branchForm = this._fb.group({
      BranchAddress: this._fb.control('', [Validators.required, 
                     Validators.maxLength(50)]),
      IFSCCode: this._fb.control('', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(10)]),
      MICRCode: this._fb.control('', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(10)])
    });
  }
  AddNewBranch() {

  }
}


How is your theming set up? Are you using a prebuilt theme, or a custom theme?

Yes, I'm using the prebuilt theams
